# angular ng-model updates parent object after submission and stay bounded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form and a display fields above it. I want to update display values only after submission. This works fine for the first submit. Until I submit it, values don't change, and once I click collect it updates values, and then, it seems that ng-model somehow binds and stay bounded to upper object, since when I continue to type on input fields values above update automatically. For me this is a strange behaviour, I want them to update only after I submit them. Any ideas?

and here is the code:

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.customFields = ["Age", "Weight", "Ethnicity"];
    $scope.person = {
        customfields: {
            "Age": 0,
                "Weight": 0,
                "Ethnicity": 0
        }
    };
    $scope.submited = {
     "person" : {
           "customfields" : {
             "Age" : 0,
                "Weight" : 0,
                "Ethnicity" : 0
             }
         }
    };

    $scope.collectData = function () {
        $scope.submited.person.customfields = $scope.person.customfields;
        console.log($scope.person.customfields);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="fields in submited.person.customfields">
    {{fields}}
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="field in customFields">
        <label class="control-label">{{field}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-model="person.customfields[field]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="collectData()">Collect</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

```
$scope.submited.person.customfields = $scope.person.customfields;
```

the variables become clones of each other - it's a property in JS. Hence, when you bind using that object, the values stay bound. You're basically just creating another reference for an already existing object.

**angular.copy** copies only the structure and data of the object onto another. Hence, cloning takes place rather than creating a reference of the object.

Hence, change it to:

```
$scope.submited.person.customfields = angular.copy($scope.person.customfields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$scope.submited.person.customfields = $scope.person.customfields;
```

to

```
$scope.submited.person.customfields = angular.copy($scope.person.customfields);
```